# How to show an error message when email val is not available in firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My Firebase Database is look like as bellow:

[image]

I want to show an error message when email val is not available in firebase database.

And my code is

```
mRef.orderByChild("email").equalTo(val).addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);

                textView.setText("Welcome " + user.name );
                System.out.println(user.name + "\n" + user.email + "\n" + user.tell);
        }
        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                textView.setText("Welcome " + user.name );
                System.out.println(user.name + "\n" + user.email + "\n" + user.tell);

        }



        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: What's the problem? The query matches the users with `email: <val>`. If something is not working, the problem is likely in the way you implemented `ChildEventListener`. Please provide the [minimal, complete code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to improve the changes of getting help.

Comment: `new ChildEventListener...` is not valid Java code. Please [edit] your question to contain a [mcve] (including a minimal example data set **in text**), instead of this.

Comment: Hii  @FrankvanPuffelen , My problem is that , when i search with email if it available in firebase database then i get the data with that email and it,s working,but I also want to show a message for, If  giving email is not available on firebase then i want to show message like invalid user.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen , The above code is only work for if email <val> is available on firebase. I want to show an error message if email. <val> is not available on firebase. Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `ChildEventListener` can only detect the presence of a certain child node or when a child node is changed/removed. It cannot detect the *absence* of a child. To detect that there is no value, you need a `ValueEventListener`:

```
mRef.orderByChild("email").equalTo(val).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if (dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount() == 0) {
            System.out.println("No user with email "+val);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
        throw firebaseError.toException(); // don't ignore onCancelled!
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks @FrankvanPuffelen, It's working. thank You..!

Answer (score 0):

```
mQuery = databaseReference.limitToLast(1).orderByChild("email").equalTo(category);

        mQuery.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Log.i(TAG, "onDataChange: "+dataSnapshot.toString());
                GenericTypeIndicator<Map<String,UserModel>> t=new GenericTypeIndicator<Map<String,UserModel>>(){};

                try{
                      Map<String,UserModel> userList=dataSnapshot.getValue(t);
                }catch(Exception exception){
                    //Error UserInfo not present in firebase
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
               //Error wile accessing database
            }
        });
```